# Highlighting of TikZ figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a way to highlight a particular area in a TikZ figure I generated. To be more specific, I have a TikZ figure that illustrates there are two octahedral. After I have shown this figure for the first time, I want to reuse it later in my document when I discuss specific concepts in more detail. To make clear which concept of the figure is discussed, I want to highlight the first and the second octahedral of the figure. Is there a simple way to do this?

The diagram is the following

```
 \begin{tikzcd}
{a_{0,1}} \arrow[r, "{e_{0,1,2}}"] & {a_{0,2}} \arrow[r, "{e_{0,2,3}}"] \arrow[d, "{e_{2,0,1}}"] & {a_{0,3}} \arrow[r, "{e_{0,3,4}}"] \arrow[d, "{e_{3,0,1}}"] & {a_{0,4}} \arrow[d, "{e_{4,0,1}}"]                          &                         \\
                                   & {a_{1,2}} \arrow[r, "{e_{1,2,3}}"] \arrow[lu, squiggly]               & {a_{1,3}} \arrow[r, "{e_{1,3,4}}"] \arrow[d, "{e_{3,1,2}}"] & {a_{1,4}} \arrow[d, "{e_{4,1,2}}"] \arrow[r, "{e_{1,0,4}}"] & {a_{0,1}[1]} \arrow[d]  \\
                                   &                                                             & {a_{2,3}} \arrow[r, "{e_{2,3,4}}"] \arrow[lu, squiggly]               & {a_{2,4}} \arrow[d, "{e_{4,2,3}}"] \arrow[r, "{e_{2,0,4}}"] & {a_{0,2}[1]} \arrow[d]  \\
                                   &                                                             &                                                             & {a_{3,4}} \arrow[lu, squiggly] \arrow[r, "{e_{3,0,4}}"]               & {a_{0,3}[1]} \arrow[d]  \\
                                   &                                                             &                                                             &                                                             & {a_{0,4}[1]} \arrow[lu, squiggly]
\end{tikzcd}\]
I want to highlight the first octahedral which is the following  

    \[\begin{tikzcd}
a_{01} \arrow[r] & a_{02} \arrow[r] \arrow[d]  & a_{03} \arrow[d]              &                        \\
                 & a_{12} \arrow[r] \arrow[lu,squiggly] & a_{13} \arrow[d] \arrow[r]    & {a_{01}[1]} \arrow[d]  \\
                 &                             &  a_{23}  \arrow[lu,squiggly] \arrow[r] & {a_{02}[1] } \arrow[d] \\
                 &                             &                               & {a_{03}[1]} \arrow[lu,squiggly]
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome! Please help us help you and provide a simple, compilable example with all the preamble and needed packages. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/why-does-tex-require-such-elaborate-mwes

Comment: And, in which form do you want to do highlighting? Change the text and draw color, or maybe add a frame?

Comment: If you want to reuse a TikZ image, you can use a pic or savebox.

Comment: I just want to add a frame, how I can do that

Comment: Are there any help please

Answer (score 1):

By checking `tikz-cd`'s implementation [`tikzlibrarycd.code.tex`](https://github.com/astoff/tikz-cd/blob/master/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex), I get to know following facts:

- An `tikzcd` environment is currently a `tikzpicture` env
- `tikzcd`'s env content is wrapped in `\matrix[matrix of (math) nodes]\bgroup <env content> \egroup;`.
- The `<opt-arg>` in `\begin{tikzcd}[<opt-arg>]` is passed to `tikzpicture`.

Therefore a frame can be drawn by first give the matrix a name, then add drawing codes at the end of picture. Two framing ways are shown, namely `\node[draw, fit=<list of nodes>] {};` and the normal `\draw`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, fit}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[
  every matrix/.append style={name=mtx}, 
  execute at end picture={
    \node[fit=(mtx-1-1) (mtx-3-3), draw=red] {};
    \draw[blue] (mtx-2-5.north west) rectangle (mtx-4-5.south east);
  }]
      {a_{0,1}} \arrow[r, "{e_{0,1,2}}"] 
    & {a_{0,2}} \arrow[r, "{e_{0,2,3}}"] \arrow[d, "{e_{2,0,1}}"] 
    & {a_{0,3}} \arrow[r, "{e_{0,3,4}}"] \arrow[d, "{e_{3,0,1}}"] 
    & {a_{0,4}} \arrow[d, "{e_{4,0,1}}"]
  \\
    & {a_{1,2}} \arrow[r, "{e_{1,2,3}}"] \arrow[lu, squiggly] 
    & {a_{1,3}} \arrow[r, "{e_{1,3,4}}"] \arrow[d, "{e_{3,1,2}}"] 
    & {a_{1,4}} \arrow[d, "{e_{4,1,2}}"] \arrow[r, "{e_{1,0,4}}"] 
    & {a_{0,1}[1]} \arrow[d]
  \\
    &
    & {a_{2,3}} \arrow[r, "{e_{2,3,4}}"] \arrow[lu, squiggly]
    & {a_{2,4}} \arrow[d, "{e_{4,2,3}}"] \arrow[r, "{e_{2,0,4}}"] 
    & {a_{0,2}[1]} \arrow[d]
  \\
    &
    &
    & {a_{3,4}} \arrow[lu, squiggly] \arrow[r, "{e_{3,0,4}}"]
    & {a_{0,3}[1]} \arrow[d]
  \\
    &
    &
    &
    & {a_{0,4}[1]} \arrow[lu, squiggly]
\end{tikzcd}\]

I want to highlight the first octahedral which is the following

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    a_{01} \arrow[r]
    & a_{02} \arrow[r] \arrow[d]
    & a_{03} \arrow[d]
  \\
    & a_{12} \arrow[r] \arrow[lu,squiggly] 
    & a_{13} \arrow[d] \arrow[r]
    & {a_{01}[1]} \arrow[d]
  \\
    &
    & a_{23} \arrow[lu,squiggly] \arrow[r] 
    & {a_{02}[1] } \arrow[d]
  \\
    &
    &
    & {a_{03}[1]} \arrow[lu,squiggly]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]